# How to update a record based on a combo box determined by a combo box?

Tags: ms-access

I have `tbl_1`:

```
+-------+---------+
| fld_A |  fld_B  |
+-------+---------+
|     1 |         |
|     2 |         |
|     3 | str_3   |
|     4 | str_4   |
|     5 | str_5   |
+-------+---------+
```

And `tbl_2`:

```
+-------+---------+
| fld_C |  fld_D  |
+-------+---------+
|     1 | str_1_X |
|     1 | str_1_Y |
|     2 | str_2_X |
|     2 | str_2_Y |
|     3 | str_3_X |
|     3 | str_3_Y |
+-------+---------+
```

I want to update `tbl_1` with data from `tbl_2` using a form (`frm_1`) which has two combo boxes on it: `cbo_1` and `cbo_2`.

The Control Source for `cbo_1` is `fld_A` and the Row Source is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl_1.fld_A
FROM tbl_1
WHERE (((tbl_1.fld_B) Is Null));
```

The Row Source is working fine and displays both `1` and `2`. The Bound column is 1.

The Control Source for `cbo_2` is `fld_B` and the Row Source is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl_2.fld_D, tbl_2.fld_C
FROM tbl_2
WHERE (((tbl_2.fld_C)=[Forms]![frm_1].[cbo_1]));
```

The Row Source is working fine, e.g. displays `str_1_X` and `str_1_Y` when `1` is selected in `cbo_1`. The Bound column is 1.

I also have some VBA to ensure `cbo_2` updates on a change in `cbo_1`:

```
Private Sub cbo_1_Change()

cbo_2.Value = Null
cbo_2.Requery

End Sub
```

This also works fine.

My issue is that when I select a record from `cbo_1` and then a record from `cbo_2` then `fld_B` doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. bind form to tbl_1, cbo_1 is UNBOUND (no ControlSource) and used as criteria with code in AfterUpdate event to either apply filter or move to record, cbo_2 has ControlSource set to fld_B to save selected value
2. form and both comboboxes are UNBOUND, combobox selections used in an UPDATE action SQL
   `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_1 SET fld_B='" & Me.cbo_2 & "' WHERE fld_A=" & Me.cbo_1`

Comment: Thanks as ever @June7. First option doesn't seem to work  though - the only change I think that was needed was to unbind cbo_1. frm_1 was already bound to tbl_1 and cbo_2 had Control source already set to fld_B. Option 2 worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Option 1 needs code - either apply filter or move to record. Can even use combobox build wizard to generate code. If answer resolves issue, please mark as accepted. Upvotes are nice as well.